# Subtracting 2 hours from a cell using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, time

I need to search a column in such a way that if the value in the column is "Soccer", the time should be adjusted in column 5 by 2 hours (Subtract two hours from the current time in Column 5). The format in Column 5 is dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm.

I am struggling to subtract two hours and replace with new time from VBA.

Any ideas?

KP

Comment: You must do more research. Use Google for your help.

Comment: Google the `DateAdd` function which will do what you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Check this formula, it is easily available on GOOGLE.

```
=IF(UPPER(A1)="SOCCER",E1-(2/24),"No change")
```

Where,

1. A1 is the column which contains "SOCCER"
2. E1 is the column which contains "Time"

Answer (score 0):

The `TimeSerial(<hours>, <minutes>, <seconds>)` VBA function makes quick work of creating a time value you easily set. It equates to the native worksheet `TIME(<hour>, <minutes>, <seconds>)` function.

```
Dim rw As Long
With ActiveSheet
    For r = .Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If CBool(InStr(1, .Cells(r, "B").Value, "soccer", vbTextCompare)) _
          And IsDate(.Cells(r, 5).Value) Then _
            .Cells(r, 5) = .Cells(r, 5).Value - TimeSerial(2, 0, 0)
    Next r
End With
```

I've checked column B for any use of *soccer* (e.g. *soccer, soccer Mom, soccer game, indoor soccer, etc*). There needs to be a date in column 5 (E:E) before the cell is backdated 2 hours.